# Can't hear difference between /j/ and /ʎ/

Tags: ipa, laterals

As in title; I can't hear difference between /j/ and /ʎ/. I also cannot reliably pronounce /ʎ/. Can any of you help me?

Sorry if this is not the right place to ask this.

Comment: What is your native language?

Comment: @J.Siebeneichler English

Comment: Which language are you trying to learn that has these sounds? If it's Spanish, the answer is simple :-)

Comment: Spanish: not really. In Cuzco it's ʎ, in Imbabura it's ʒ, in Lima it seems to be j.

Comment: @J.Siebeneichler It is Spanish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the asker has clarified that the language in question is Spanish, the likely explanation is that they are hearing the pronunciation in a dialect that exhibits [yeísmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye%C3%ADsmo), which causes /j/ and /ʎ/ to be pronounced the same (usually [ʝ]).

If that's not the case, what I recommend is finding some minimal pairs in languages that have these phones and listen to them until you can recognise the difference. My native language, Portuguese, does; here are the links to the pronunciations of the minimal pair [*malha*](http://forvo.com/word/malha/#pt) (with /ʎ/) and [*maia*](http://forvo.com/word/maia/#pt) (with /j/).

Comment: I've also been listening to the audio provided by the Wikipedia articles on the sounds. (I'll have to listen to your links a bunch before I get it, probably.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate (adequate) examples of [ʎ] in some language. Avoid made-up pronunciations by English-speaking linguists. It exists in Italian, Portuguese, Catalan and some dialects of Spanish and Hungarian, among the more widely-spoken languages, as well as some more obscure languages like Cuzco Quechua, Aymara, Saami. It also exists in a number of Slavic languages though it behaves there like a "palatalized l". Then listen to examples that have [j] versus [ʎ] in comparable environments, until you get to the point that you can hear the difference. Forvo.com has lots of recordings for major languages (and 4,709 recordings of North Saami)